# SAML assertion using java

Tags: java, saml

I am a java developer, and I have got a url `protocol://common_domain_name/sps/federation_name/saml20/login` (I can not give real url for security and legal purpose), this is said endpoint url. I need to do something call SSO (Single sign on for user authentication i.e., user-name and password are right that is in another server). How do I do that? This is totally unknown to me.

Can anyone please help guide me through it?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the [many SAML implementations](http://saml.xml.org/wiki/saml-open-source-implementations) for Java. A good choice is probably [OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home/).